# I can't get data from AJAX post request in C# controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to send data from javascript to c# controller using ajax, but when the Add method in my controller is called all its arguments are null

AJAX:

```
function addRequest(name, price, about){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Services/Add',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {
            'name'  : name ,
            'price' : price,
            'about' : about,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: (insert) => {
            if (insert) {
                $('#result').fadeIn(200).html(insert).fadeOut(200, () => {
                    location.reload()
                })
            }
        }
    })
}
```

My controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ServicesController: Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Add")]
    public async Task Add(string? name, string? price, string? about)
    {
        await Context.Services.AddAsync(new Service
        {
            Name = name,
            Price = price,
            About = about
        });
        await Context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the contentType and dataType properties on your $.ajax call. The contentType property is for telling the server what data to expect in the request. The dataType property is for the dataType you are expecting back from the server, and you aren't returning any data.

Answer (score 1):

I think [binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0) of this controller in not working, you are sending object by ajax but you are expecting three separte primitives

try:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Add")]
    public async Task Add(Service service)
    {
     await Context.Services.AddAsync(service);
    }
```

or try adding setup [binding attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#frombody-attribute)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Add")]
public async Task Add(Service model) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a service class to receive the JSON rather using distinct values.

Follow below links to learn more.
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Pass-Send-Model-object-in-jQuery-ajax-POST-request-to-Controller-method-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-how-to-use-ajax-with-parameters/

Answer (score 0):

I get better results using the $.post() method of the jquery library
here is an example:

```
$.post(`Services/Add/?name=${name}&price=${price}&about=${about}`,
    function (insert) {
     if (insert) {
                $('#result').fadeIn(200).html(insert).fadeOut(200, () => {
                    location. Reload()
                })
            }
    });
```

Source: [JQuery Documentation about $.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: from your linked doc: "This is a shorthand Ajax function, which is equivalent to: `$.ajax({
  type: "POST", ...`"  - which the OP is using

Comment: That is true, the real difference is that I'm passing the arguments as part of the url. I find it works better in this context as this assures the method gets what is expected. And since you don't need to modify any other option on the ajax call, this syntax is more concise and shows the intended purpose of the call. Finally, is a tool we can use so why not use it and save a couple of lines if everything will be left as default?

Answer (score -1):

Check if your controller is authorized or not. If you want the controller to work without any authorization then you have to add allowannoymous attribute on your controller since no access token is given in the ajax call.

Comment: If this would be an authorization issue the controller wouldn´t be called in the first place.